# Facebook login button

Tags: facebook, facebook-api

Есть код кнопки

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-width="100%" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-button-type="continue_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="true" data-scope="public_profile, email, user_birthday"></div>
```

По непонятным причинам, кнопка простая, а должна была бы быть Continue as {Name}.
Было перепробовано большое количество вариантов, ничего не помогает.

Answer (score 1):

Полазил в документации и поэксперементировал, вот наблюдения. Кнопка "Продолжить как User" отображается в таком виде только если пользователь вошел в Facebook ранее и срок действия авторизации еще не истек. В противном случае кнопка отображается как "Вход через Facebook"